# Power BI to show a list of the titles instead of id's

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table that references other tables in a 1:* relationship. The tables are retrieved from Sharepoint and this table references id's delimited by ";" in the reference columns. I would like to show the title instead of the id of the referenced table.  Example:

```
tableA
Id title tableBId
1   asd    1; 2;

tableB
Id title
1   Acb
2   bcb 

resultTableA
Id title tableBTitle
1   asd   Acb; bcb;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a custom column in Table A using the code below.

What this does for each row is:

1. Counts how many delimited values are in the tableBId column
2. Create a temporary version of the tableBId column replacing "; " and ";" with "|"
3. Create a series of numbers from 1 to the count of delimited values
4. Get a list of BTitles from that series of numbers, getting pieces from the temporary version (with "|") and then looking those IDs up into table B.
5. Returning a concatenation of the titles from the list.

   ```
   tableBTitle = 
   VAR DelimCount = LEN([tableBId]) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE([tableBId], ";", ""))
   VAR PathIDs = SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE([tableBId], "; ", "|"), ";", "|")
   VAR Series = GENERATESERIES(1, DelimCount)
   VAR BTitles = ADDCOLUMNS(Series, "BTitle", LOOKUPVALUE(tableB[title], tableB[Id], VALUE(PATHITEM(PathIDs, [Value]))))
   RETURN
       CONCATENATE(CONCATENATEX(BTitles, [BTitle], "; "), ";")
   ```

This was created by using pieces found [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/DAX-how-split-a-string-by-delimiter-into-a-list-or-array/td-p/559597) and [here](http://sqljason.com/2013/06/split-delimited-row-into-multiple-rows.html).

Learn more about `CONCATENATEX` [here](https://dax.guide/concatenatex/).

Comment: AGCO = 
VAR DelimCount = LEN([AGCOId]) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE([AGCOId], ";", ""))
VAR PathIDs = SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE([AGCOId], "; ", "|"), ";", "|")
VAR Series = GENERATESERIES(1, DelimCount)
VAR BTitles = ADDCOLUMNS(Series, "BTitle", LOOKUPVALUE('AGCO Mapping'[Title], 'AGCO Mapping'[Id], VALUE(PATHITEM(PathIDs, [Value]))))
RETURN
    CONCATENATE(CONCATENATEX(BTitles, [BTitle], "; "), ";") Error: Function 'LOOKUPVALUE' does not support comparing values of type Text with values of type Number. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values. :/

Comment: Two things. First check that the ID column in Table B is a number data type. If you can change it to a number, try that. Second, you can try dropping the `VALUE` before `PATHITEM` (remember to delete the starting and ending parentheses).

Comment: I changed to number and the error was gone but the resultColumn is showing only ";" in every row... :(

Comment: That would indicate that the ID's in the delimited list are not being found in Table B. Alternatively, it may indicate that the "delimited" list of IDs does not have a delimiter.
I'm not sure I can offer any other support unless you update your question with more data and table structure (data types).